# adding extra inline css attributes with ContentImageByID

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, css, html

I have the following code which works fine, however the image loads at its original width at 540px. 
I would like to change the width of the image. I've tried adding style to `<td>` but it doesn't seem to work. What can I add to the following html code to set max-width of 270px?

**AMPSCRIPT**

```
SET @ImageId = "28034"
SET @FeatureImage1 = ContentImagebyID(@ImageId)
 ]%%
```

I've tried using the following **HTML** which results in no changes to the width of the image:

```
<td align="center" class="fluid" style="width: 100%; max-width: 270px; height: auto; padding: 0px; text-align: center;" width="270">
                 <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="http://" target="_blank" title="">%%=v(@FeatureImage1)=%%</a></td>
```

If I don't use the `ContentImagebyID`, it works fine with the following code, however I need a solution as I am wanting to dynamically populate an area in the table.

```
<td align="center" class="fluid">
<a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="http://" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="Alt-Text" data-assetid="19943" src="http://image.companya.com/lib/fe4115707564067d701674/m/1/80e426bc-1964-41a2-a48c-34298e8fbbd8.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-width: 270px; height: auto; padding: 0px; text-align: center;" width="270"></a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's much easier to manually add the image URLs now that you can enable the [**Predictable File URLs**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_administration.htm&type=5) in the Content Builder Administration settings.

It's better than working around the annoyances of the [**ContentImagebyID**](https://ampscript.guide/contentimagebyid) function, in my opinion.

Comment: Yup - I couldn't take a shortcut but had to create individual content blocks with corresponding urls. Thank you!

Comment: Sweet. Would you mind checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at this [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).